# `ExceptionHandling` not found?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api

I'm referencing `System.Web.Http.dll`, full path:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Http\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Http.dll
```

However, I'm getting a compile exception saying that it can't find `ExceptionHandling` in the `System.Web.Http` namespace.

```
The type or namespace name 'ExceptionHandling' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web.Http' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

Looking in the file, it is indeed not there.

I have been updating NuGet packages, so I'm assuming it's been moved\replaced with something.

Where do I need to go now to get this namespace?  The internet seems quite quiet on this.

Comment: How you use Exceptionhandling in your code ? Can you please provide that ?

Answer (score 2):

OK, the solution was odd.  Not sure how the project ended up in this state.

The fact that the reference was pointing to `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Http\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Http.dll` showed that it wasn't using the assemblies provided by the package, which were in the `packages` folder.

I had to explicitly delete the references, then roll back the version of `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core` as VS wouldn't let me uninstall it as the project wouldn't compile (at least I assume that was why, never had that before though).

That re-added the assemblies with the correct paths, that being, paths to the packages folder.

Answer (score 0):

I also stuck and your suggest solve my problem
my step is here

1. remove Reference System.Web.Http
2. remove Nuget Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core
3. restart Visual Studio
4. try to install Nuget Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core again